# PDF is not showing inside object tag with object URL

Tags: javascript, pdf, createobjecturl

I'm using object tag to display PDF inside it.

`data` for PDF looks like this "blob:http://localhost:4200/c91f1c30-0c97-45cc-a5f5-4897f3766f60".

Firefox can open and show document; Chrome for some reason don't render it.
Is Chrome don't support object URLs in object? Or there is other problem?

When I'm starting using iframe - Chrome will show PDF, buy Firefox will download it instead of preview.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like adobe provides a free API to embed PDF files, this could be a better way going forward?

https://developer.adobe.com/document-services/apis/pdf-embed/